# cannot save pdf in IE

Tags: html, ajax, wcf, pdf

I am able to download and save other types of files in Internet Explorer and I am able to download and save pdf types in Firefox.  But in IE8, I cannot download a pdf file.  I've checked the wcf code, it is returning a file stream and as I've already mentioned, it does work on other types of files, like .xlsx.

Here is my form on the html page

```
<div>
  <form id="frmdownloadData" action="http://localhost:9433/NASWcf1/runDownloadFile" 
     method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" id="UserId" name="UserId" value="****" />
  File Name: <input id="filename" name="filename" type="text" value=""/>
  <br />
  App Code: <input id="appcode" name="appcode" type="text" value="Appcode_FileId"  />
  </form>
</div>
<input type="button" id="submitdwnldfrm" onclick="dofileDownload()" />
```

here is the script for the dofileDownload()

```
function dofileDownload() {
        $('#frmdownloadData').ajaxSubmit(function () {
            alert("Thank you for your comment!");
        });
    }
```

Befopre returning the file stream from the wcf, I set this property:
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

I've also tried setting it to "application/pdf" but it doesn't help.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean 'it doesn't work'? Does IE try to load the pdf in the browser instead of saving the file? Can you try from other machines?

Comment: IE can be quirky with the Adobe plugin, if I recall. Try changing the POST to a GET, or sometimes we've had to open a blank browser window, then set the window.location to the PDF url after it's opened.

Comment: it doesn't load it or try to save it. I'm working on a Windows 7, 64 bit virtual machine. Its IE8 and I think its also 64 bit. The code I posted works in Firefox, but fails in Chrome and Windows. So maybe there is a better way to do this. The only tools I have to use, (design requirements) are ajax and WCF.

Also, there is no url for the .pdf file.  This is part of a intranet web app that allows the users to peruse a folder, select a file then download that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution:
Set the ContentType = "application/x-unknown"
then add this header
"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.ext;"

Sample code below:

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType   = "application/x-unknown";
                System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="+filename+";");
```